# mysqli_query( ) no ejecuta mi consulta

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, wampserver

O al menos eso entiendo. He estado codificando una pagina en php y la conecté a mi base de datos en phpmyadmin. En la pagina principal extraigo datos desde la base de datos sin ningún problema. Pero en el archivo registro.php, que es un formulario en otra interfaz diferente, que tengo no me está ejecutando la variable de consulta que tengo, para explicarme mejor muestro los siguientes anexos:

> Esta es la estructura de mi carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> este es mi archivo conexión.php

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "baseprueba");
if ($connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER , DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) ){
}
?>
```

> El index.php no es necesario mostrarlo creo yo, es muy extenso, aún así dejo la captura de mi referencia a la interfaz registro.php en el navbar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Este es mi formulario, que está en el archivo Registro.php

```
<form class="form-contenedor" method="post" action="agregar.php">
        <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomber" class="form-label">Nombres: </label> <h style="color:red;"> *</h>
                <input class="form-control" name="Nombres" type="text" required maxlength="30">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomber" class="form-label">Apellidos: </label> <h style="color:red;"> *</h>
                <input class="form-control" name="Apellidos" type="text" required maxlength="30">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomber" class="form-label">Telefono / Celular: </label> <h style="color:red;"> *</h>
                <input class="form-control" name="Telefono" type="text" required maxlength="30">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nomber" class="form-label">Contraseña: </label> <h style="color:red;"> *</h>
                <input class="form-control" name="Contraseña" type="text"  required maxlength="15">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" name="registrar" value="Regístrate" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>

        </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php include("agregar.php");?>
```

> Este es mi archivo agregar.php

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['registrar'])){
    if (strlen($_POST['Nombres']) >= 1 && strlen($_POST['Apellidos']) >=1 &&   strlen($_POST["Telefono"]) >=1 && strlen($_POST["Contraseña"]) >=1){
    $nombres = $_POST["Nombres"];
    $apellidos = $_POST["Apellidos"];
    $contraseñas = $_POST["Contraseña"];
    $telefono = $_POST["Telefono"];
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellidos, telefono, contraseña) VALUES ('$nombres', '$apellidos', '$telefono', '$contraseñas')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($connect,$consulta);
        if($resultado){
            ?>
            <h3>Se ha registrado</h3>
            <?php
        } else{
            ?>
            <h3>¡Oups ha ocurrido un error!</h3>
            <?php
            echo "$nombres";
            echo "$apellidos";
            echo "$contraseñas";
            echo "$telefono";
        }
    } else {
        ?>
        <h3>¡Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
        <?php
    }
}
```

> Por último esta es la tabla y la base de datos con las que trabajo, hay más tablas, pero para el registro solo necesito esa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los registros los inserté directamente desde el phpmyadmin, incluso usé el insert de mi código con los datos de las variables que capturan mis variables $_POST y me permitió insertar.
Quiero agregar que cambié la consulta para ver si había algo mal, y pasó esto:

> $consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (nombre, apellidos, telefono, contraseña) VALUES ('$nombres', '$apellidos', '$telefono', '$contraseñas')";

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> $consulta = "select * from usuario";

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De ahí sale el motivo de mi título, no sé que podría ser, es mi primera vez usando php y mysql

> Si quieren ver el proyecto completo, les anexo el link a mi carpeta drive:
> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RtfOp01uNWmgCNPeMLxPjlCGU0eU9J9l?usp=sharing

Comment: Evita hacer uso de caracteres especiales, como el caso de la ñ, para variables o campos de una tabla. Por lo pronto agrega esta linea al final de mysqli_query or die(mysqli_error($connect));

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) VALUES ('Jampier', 'Ventura Hernández', '987456321', 'ecsse')' at line 1

Comment: Tenías razón, no sabía lo de los carácteres especiales, muchas gracias